# How to move the value of a floating point register to a general-purpose register in MIPS?

Tags: assembly, mips

I have the following bit of MIPS assembly, run on the [MARS](http://courses.missouristate.edu/KenVollmar/MARS/) simulator, given below:

```
.data

x: .space 4 # 4 bytes = 32 bits

li $v0, 6
syscall
```

At this point, the floating point value I need is in `$f0`, but I need to move the value to `x`. If I could transfer the contents of the floating point register `$f0` to `$t0`, I would be able to do this. Is this possible? If not, what is the workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the ['single precision store' pseudoinstruction](http://chortle.ccsu.edu/AssemblyTutorial/Chapter-31/ass31_5.html).  I think this one should stick whatever 32 bits are in `$f0` to `x`.

```
s.s $f0, x
```

I just went and downloaded MARS and tested it out, it works fine here.